# importing image on canvas html5

Tags: image, html, canvas

```js
var img = new Image();
img.src = '/images/backdrop.jpg';
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

I wanted to load an image from local disk on to canvas using dialog box mechanism rather than the path directly specified as in above example. I tried different sorts using JavaScript but in vain, even tried using the input type as file. What else can I try?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Take a look here:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images

It's important to have `drawImage` call after the image has loaded:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    var ctx = document.getElementById('ctx').getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}
img.src = 'images/backdrop.jpg';
```

Also, note that you probably want to use `images/backdrop.jpg` instead of `/images/backdrop.jpg` (note there's no slash in front), as using the latter would get the image from root directory, I would assume that's probably not where your images are.

As far as loading from a dialog box, you can replace the last line from the above with something like this:

```
var name = prompt("Enter the name of the file", "backdrop.jpg");
img.src = 'images/' + name;
```

This way, the user would be able to enter the name of the image file to load it. Of course, you need to have that file in your `images` folder.

Hope this helps.