# How to upload images to canvas, when user uploads images

Tags: php, html, canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [importing image on canvas html5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868259/importing-image-on-canvas-html5)

My question:

I would like to let users upload images and when they have uploaded the image file it automatically displays it in a canvas element.

My code so far:

```
<html>
<head>
<link class="jsbin" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="jsbin" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script>

   function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function (e) {
                    $('#blah')
                        .attr('src', e.target.result)
                       // .width(500)
                        //.height(500);
                };

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }



</script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>JS Bin</title>
<!--[if IE]>
  <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<style>
  article, aside, figure, footer, header, hgroup, 
  menu, nav, section { display: block; }
</style>
</head>
<body>



  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" /> <br> <br>
    <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image" />


<?php



?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This will only display the image, not putting it in a canvas element, what my question is.

Comment: Thank you, but it's not the same question, at your post the image is static.

Comment: The technique is the same, the only difference if you need to set the  path + filename of the newly uploaded image.

Comment: Could you explain your solution in code please. Not sure what you mean. Thank you.